# minimum number of coincidences is greater than

Tags: sql, count, distinct, having

I don't know how to solve this: there are 3 tables (project, engineer and client). I want to know the names of the clients that have hired 2 or more **different** engineers who earn more than X.

The table "project" contains the id's of client and engineer, and other parameters. The info about the name of the client and the salary of the engineer is contained in "client" and "engineer" respectivelly.

```
select name 
from client, project
where project.client_number IN
    (
    select p.client_number
    from project p inner join engineer e on (p.eng_number=e.eng_number)
    where e.salary>50000
    group by p.client_number
    having count (distinct p.eng_number)>2
    )

group by client.name
;
```

Comment: what you have tried?

Comment: Post your table structures and also some sample data, also what SBMS you are using

Comment: GROUP BY, HAVING, COUNT DISTINCT...

Answer (score 1):

You were quite close:

```
select name 
from client
where client_number IN
  (
    select p.client_number
    from project p inner join engineer e on (p.eng_number=e.eng_number)
    where e.salary>50000
    group by p.client_number
    having count (distinct p.eng_number)>2
  )
```

Comment: Oh! I could have spent 24h more hours and still not be able to find out! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand you correctly but this approach should work with minor modifications:
start with the engineer earning more than 50000 :

```
(select * from engineer where salary>50000 ) e
```

join the project table:

```
inner join 
(select * from projects ) p -- this is overkill - just to give an option to filter on this level can be replaced by projects p
on (p.eng_number=e.eng_number)
```

now join the clients table

```
inner join 
(select * from clients ) c  -- this is overkill - just to give an option to filter on this level. can be replaced by clients c
on (p.client_number=e.client_number)
```

now you can wrap it up with an external select with whatever filters and group by

```
select name from (
(select * from engineer where salary>50000 ) e
inner join 
(select * from projects ) p 
on (p.eng_number=e.eng_number)
inner join 
(select * from clients ) c  
on (p.client_number=e.client_number)
) epc
group by c.client_number
having count (distinct p.eng_number)>2
```

Comment: Thank you, is is pretty step by step and very useful!

Comment: I'm glad... the answer below clearly fixes your problem. I tried a sort of general layout